# Angular service causing an error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to receive data using `$http` as a dependency injection, then assign that data to a promise using angular's `$q` service. I'm doing something wrong.. can't seem to locate where.

**Service**:

```
myApp.factory('githubApi', ['$http', '$q',
    function($http, $q) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        //Declaring a promise that will or will not return a users github information.
        this.accountInformation = function (){
            return $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/joshspears3')
            .then(function(response){
                deferred.resolve(response);
                return deferred.promise;
            }, function(response){
                deferred.reject(response);
                return deferred.promise;
            })
        }
    }
]);
```

**Controller**:

```
myApp.controller('githubCtrl', [ 'githubApi', '$q', '$scope',
    function(githubApi, $q, $scope){
        githubApi.accountInformation()
        .then(
            function (result) {
                $scope.data = result;
            }, function (error) {
                // handle errors here
                console.log(error.statusText);
            }
        );
    }
]);
```

**Directive**:

```
myApp.directive('githubRequest', [
    function() {
        return {
            scope: {},
            restrict: 'E',
            controller: 'githubCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'public/views/partials/github-request.html'
        }
    }
]);
```

**Partial** (github-request.html):

```
<p class="component-example-header">Creating a service. Making a $http request to grab my personal Github information.</p>
<div class="service-message">
    <p>Avatar:</p>
    <img width="20%" src="{{data.avatar_url}}" alt="" />
    <p>Username: <span ng-bind="data.login"></span></p>
    <p>Followers: <span ng-bind="data.followers"></span>, Following: <span ng-bind="data.following"></span></p>
</div>
<hr>
```

This is the **error** that the browser is throwing:

```
Error: [$injector:undef] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/$injector/undef?p0=githubApi
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:9999/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:6:416
    at Object.$get (http://localhost:9999/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:37:32)
    at Object.e [as invoke] (http://localhost:9999/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:39:96)
    at http://localhost:9999/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:40:410
    at d (http://localhost:9999/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:38:308)
    at Object.e [as invoke] (http://localhost:9999/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:39:64)
    at Q.instance (http://localhost:9999/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:80:151)
    at K (http://localhost:9999/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:61:140)
    at http://localhost:9999/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:68:475
```

It's saying that my githubApi service is undefined when I inject it into my dependencies for possibly my controller?

Comment: Could you use angular with no minification in order to have more details on error ?

Comment: Did you try to copy the [link](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/$injector/undef?p0=githubApi) on the first line of the `Error:` message into your favorite web browser? The examples included in those links may shed some light on the actual problem (for future reference).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* it's because your factory isn't returning anything

```
myApp.factory('githubApi', ['$http', '$q',
    function($http, $q) {
       return {
          accountInformation: function (){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/joshspears3')
            .then(function(response){
                deferred.resolve(response);
            }, function(response){
                deferred.reject(response);
            })
            return deferred.promise;
          }
       }
    }
]);
```

is how I usually have mine

Comment: @JoshSpears I made an edit, you should be returning deferred.promise outside of the promise, not after resolving the promise

Comment: Still causing an error: 
Unknown provider: githubApiProvider <- githubApi <- githubCtrl

Comment: Thats because the function is returning an object that declares a property with =, should be : instead.

Comment: @taxicala nice catch, didn't get it deleted when I changed his function to an object property

Answer (score 2):

You should be returning the promise in your service method instead, and the deferred object should be inside the method, also, the service should return an object:

```
myApp.factory('githubApi', ['$http', '$q',
    function($http, $q) {
        //Declaring a promise that will or will not return a users github information.
        return {
            accountInformation: function () {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/joshspears3')
                    .then(function(response){
                        deferred.resolve(response);
                    }, function(response){
                        deferred.reject(response);
                    });
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

You can also simplify this as the `$http` service already returns a promise:

```
myApp.factory('githubApi', ['$http',
    function($http) {
        //Declaring a promise that will or will not return a users github information.
        return {
            accountInformation: function () {
                return $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/joshspears3');
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

First, `$http.get` returns a `$q` promise already, there is no need to wrap it in a promise again.

Second, a factory creates a single instance of a service which is shared. Therefore the method for the factory should return that object. Assigning anything to this within the factory function itself will not expose that method / property:

```
myApp.factory('githubApi', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var githubApi = {
      accountInformation: function () {
          return $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/joshspears3');
      }
    };
    return githubApi;
}
```